# Combobox with fixed text

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am trying to set a fixed text inside a combobox, but a cannot "overwrite" the default behaviour that it always set the text to the SelectedItem.ToString(). Is there a way to do this?

My current combobox looks like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ddlSection"
                Text="Hello World!"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</ComboBox>
```

In this combobox there should always be the text "Hello World!" be displayed no matter what item is selected, the only way I can achieve this right now is using the SelectedItemChanged and reset the Text Property manually.

Comment: How user will see, that he had selected another item?

Comment: Text shall always stay Hello World but user may select different items when popup is open? How much sense it that making to you?

Comment: I know its not the default behaviour, and that the user will not see whats currently selected but its kinda hard to explain why exactly I need it. So yes, thats exactly what I want and I am sorry it doesnt make any sense to you, but is there a way to do it.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do it. Use DataTemplates or ControlTemplates.

Comment: @devhedgehog Could you pls provide a more explained answer, and again not that you recommend the same as gleng, that items within the popup should stay as is and display "correctly" only the textbox (within a comboxbox) should display a different value ("Hello World!").

Comment: madd0 provided you a nice example. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the template of your `ComboBox`. You can create a copy by right clicking then selecting *Edit Template* > *Edit a Copy...*

In the original template you will find a `ContentPresenter` whose content is bound to the selected element:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
    ... />
```

You can either replace this `ContentPresenter` with whatever you want to display, or simply replace the value of the `Content` property with your own binding or hard-coded value (e.g. "Hello world")

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make a custom `ItemTemplate`. Try this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Binding Sections}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World!"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Sorry, but thats not what I like to do, since this will change the Items in the list, the list shall display the correct values but only the Text should be different (fixed).

Comment: This doesn't change the items in the list. It changes the way they are displayed.

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant, and its not what I desire the items should display as is, but the text within the textbox part should always contain the same text no matter what item is selected.